# Is there a way to turn off the script in Defense Grid: The Awakening?

Tags: pc, defense-grid-awakening

I am researching this game and may buy it. One thing concerns me: the language. I know my younger sister would want to play this, but again, the language is a concern. Is there any way to silence or turn off the script. I don't really know when it would show up anyway because, again, I don't own the game. Any insight would be great!

Comment: Is this for PC or console?

Comment: @Ben Sorry, this would be for PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can silence the dialog in the audio settings:

[image]

Of course, your sister can turn it back on.

Comment: Before I accept the answer, does this setting only silence the dialog, but not prevent it from being viewed during gameplay?

Comment: What do you mean by "viewed"? It's audio.

Comment: Isn't there a text box where commanders talk to you during the game? Then does turning off the 'voice over' just silence that -- but leave the comments visible? Or does it turn that off all together. If that makes sense. (I've only seen some videos so I don't really know what the proper terms are.)

Comment: Do you mean subtitles? You can turn those off in the interface screen: https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Defense_Grid:_The_Awakening#/media/File:Defence_Grid_-_Interface.jpg

Comment: @Smock I suppose that is what I meant :).  Now, to make sure I understand this, let me ask this: Will turning off the voice over and the subtitles eliminate any encounters with the (E-10+) language?